# Any way to export Sessions from MremoteNG to RDCman?

Tags: mremoteng

so I have many connections on Mremote. In forums and on it's own page I can't find a way to move my connections to Mremote to RDCman.

The problem is that Mremote creates both a XML or a CSV file, and RDCman can only reads RDG file extensions.